# Mounting smb/Windows drive isn't working after upgrade to 17.10

Tags: mount, samba, cifs

I just updated my PC from Ubuntu 17.04 to 17.10.  I'm pretty sure as I went through the dialog that I chose to update the system, but keep my existing programs and data.  However, the update does seem to have kept files from `$HOME` and under, it pretty much looks like any programs I had installed were lost.

That's OK in general, but I previously had a script I ran that would mount up a set of disks from a Windows box.  For example:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o user=larry,pass=xxxx,uid=1000,gid=1000 //10.0.0.10/CDrive /smb/asus/CDrive
```

Note these are two boxes in my house so security isn't really a concern that the password is right there.

Since the update, I get an error message: `mount error(95): Operation not supported`

I *think* I re-installed the necessary samba software, but I must have missed something.  Can someone help me out?

Comment: I guess you ran in the same problem as https://askubuntu.com/questions/967144/ubuntu-17-10-issue-with-mount-cifs Check if the solution to add a version will help you.

Comment: Yes, not sure why I didn't see your question when I searched before posting mine, but indeed the "vers=1.0" lets the mount command work.