# after upgrade to 17.10, Samba shares are not accessible from XP or Android

Tags: 17.10, samba4

I have accessed data on my Ubuntu PC (64 bit, 17.04 Gnome) from some other devices via Samba. After upgrading to 17.10 that does not work anymore, the clients keep asking for credentials.
I tried with Android ES file explorer and Windows XP.

In the log I can see that there were contacts (empty files with client IDs), but no further info.
In bug report 1703490 there was a recommendation to include in samba.conf "ntlm auth = yes", but that did not help in my case.
Likewise, "server max protocol = NT1", and "lanman auth = yes" did not help.

How can I get connection again?

Comment: this has been a common question the last few days.   samba has been upgraded and no longer uses v1 protocols by default (wannacry et.al. affecting windoze).  refer https://askubuntu.com/questions/966966/samba-mount-issue-under-ubuntu-17-10

(I know XP won't use later than SMBv1)

Comment: Windows 10 and Android do not connect, either. Seems a very successful Samba upgrade, making it unusable. Any way to use the old version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I did not find any hint anywhere, I started over. I deleted smbuser and replaced samba.conf with the original one, restarted smbd and nmbd.

Now, I only used system-config-samba to setup.
It works now, including access from XP and Android.
Comparing the tool-generated samba.conf with my previous try, I did not find significant differences, there also seems no need for "ntlm auth = yes".

Anyway, it works.